# pattern of words exists in string

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I want to find if a certain pattern of words exists in a string. As an example, in the string below,  I want to know if the words "wish" and "allow" occur. Here,  ordering matters so I want to only return True if "wish" appears before "allow".
"I wish the platform gave the ability to allow one to change settings"
Result: True 
a counter-example: 
"I allowed my setting to change, only wish this could be reversed"
Result: False

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: changed the tags so that it's a little more relevant, it has nothing much to do with `nlp` or `nltk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and created a Regex expression that meets your needs:

```
/wish(.?|.*)allow/
```

This means "find the word 'wish' anywhere in the text, followed by zero, one, or many other characters, followed by the word 'allow'".

Regex101.com is a great sandbox for building Regex expressions. Any time I'm not sure how the Regex pattern-matching should be formatted, I use this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using my concept implemented in javascript.

you always get the result apple which is appeared just before pumpkin.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the last position of the element "Apple" before pumpkin</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = ["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango","Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango","pumpkin","Apple"];
    var a = fruits.indexOf("pumpkin");
    var b = fruits.lastIndexOf("Apple",a);
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = b;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need regex for this:

```
def checkwordorder(phrase, word1, word2):
    try:
        return phrase.lower().index(word1.lower()) < phrase.lower().index(word2.lower())
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> checkwordorder('I wish the platform gave the ability to allow one to change settings', 'wish', 'allow')
True
>>> checkwordorder('I allowed my setting to change, only wish this could be reversed', 'wish', 'allow')
False
```